# How to strip www for all hosts in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I read SO topics on the matter. However, they only apply to single hosts.

I would like to have a uniform rule for all the server for current and future domains.

Basically, I want to remove www from all requets and leave only domain name to be accessible.

Apache also serves HTTPS, so how to apply this to all?

Thanks!

```
http://www.example.com >> http://example.com
https://www.example.com >> https://example.com
```

Maria

Comment: There is exactly 2074 questions with mod_rewrite tag. What exactly is being asked in those questions that is not asked in mine?

Comment: Who knows? Perhaps they escaped my attention ;) All I can tell you is that you question would be better asked on serverfault.com as per the FAQ.

Comment: @MarialKeys - Are you looking for a solution that avoids touching the `<VirtualHost>`s at all, or?

Comment: @spender - General `mod_rewrite` questions [are appropriate for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39063/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf). Depending on exactly what's being asked, this *might* be considered more of an Apache question, but it doesn't stray so far that I'm inclined to vote to move, personally. :)

Comment: Guys, this is a mod_rewrite question. But SO folks have always been helpful to me, so even though I feel insulted, I won't argue with you. If you like, I will move this to serverfault.

Comment: Tim yes, I am looking for a universal solution taht would affect all domains served by apache.

Comment: @Tim I stand corrected. @Maria, sorry for being a pain! Wouldn't hurt asking there too though.

Comment: @spender no problems at all. SO is a very helpful place thanks to you guys. I should have kept my mouth shut and asked the question there considering i helped no one here and you have 10K+ reputation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is (seemingly) impossible using `mod_rewrite`, to a particular degree.

Configurations from multiple "levels" do not stack in `mod_rewrite`, so a rule set defined in the main server configuration will not be automatically imported and applied to a request that is delegated to a `<VirtualHost>`.

However, assuming that you have to assign the `<VirtualHost>` at some point anyway, if you don't plan to have any other rules within the `<VirtualHost>` body (if they're in `.htaccess` or a `<Directory>` section, that would be fine), you could play around with the following.

In the main configuration, we'll take my [answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634101/url-rewriting-for-different-protocols-in-htaccess/3636461#3636461) and apply it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Then, in each of our `<VirtualHost>` sections, we can "import" it using the [`RewriteOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Alternatively, of course, you could simply copy the rule set to each `<VirtualHost>` in its entirety, but this keeps the relevant rule set in a single location.

Note that the reason I suggest not having additional rules in the `<VirtualHost>` directly in this case is that the inherited rules are included *after* whatever you've defined in the current level of the configuration, which could have unintended side-effects.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are a lifesaver. Works for me! It also works for the vhosts without RewriteOptions or RewriteEngine. Can you care to elaborate what exactly we are doing here?

Comment: I have a domain at #1 spot in Google with www. I think I will lose my position... but I am sick and tired of this www issue and want to get over with it once and for all.

Comment: @MarialKeys - Hmm, well, I had originally thought it should work automatically if you didn't have anything related to `mod_rewrite` in the virtual host, but I tried it on my local test server and it wasn't importing the main configuration's rule set without the explicit `inherit`. If it works for you without it, good stuff. Otherwise, what I had put will force it to pull in the rules from the main configuration. I need to review the source code again to see exactly what goes on there, since my answer may be a bit misleading about what you can and can't expect to happen automatically.

Comment: @Tim, I have rewrite rules in: <directory /var/www/html>. So it probably affects all without explicit inherit option. Can this be?

Comment: @MariaKeys - Ah, I see, that could be. I'm not 100% sure how you have your various hosts setup as far as directory roots, etc., so that does come into play. Consider what I've [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670742/what-is-the-htaccess-mod-rewrite-solution-for-this-redirect-problem/3679453#3679453) in that case, which is similar to this scenario (`<Directory>` is equivalent to `.htaccess` in this scenario)...and hopefully I can get a more clear description before I say anything overly incorrect about it.

Comment: Actually, I think I will just remove this www virus from DNS altogether.